# svelte reactive declaration on store level

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

In svelte for case where some part's of component state needs to be computed based on others we can use reactive declaration. As official doc stands https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations `$: doubled = count * 2`. I wonder why it is component level but not store level. Svelte store has no feature like this, right? The one way I see to achieve this is to create custom store, that implements `subscribe` to satisfy store contract but powered by something else that supports such approach out of the box. Let's say mobx and its `computeds`. Do I miss something important or there is no other way?

Comment: Did you have a look at derived stores? https://svelte.dev/tutorial/derived-stores  -- 
 https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-derived

Comment: @Corrl That should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are `derived stores` in Svelte, whose value is computed based on one or more other stores
[tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/derived-stores) - [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-derived) - [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7c52bef79ec94ba4aeba8648a84fa6d9?version=3.47.0)

```
import {writable, derived} from 'svelte/store'

export const count = writable(2)

export const doubled = derived(count, $count => $count * 2)
```